# Virtualbox kernel module not loaded

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, dkms

I am trying to use Virtualbox 7.0.10 on Ubuntu with kernal 6.4.10 but I get this error.

```
    vboxmanage -version
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (6.4.10-060410-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
7.0.10r158379
```

I think the problem is related to the DKMS installation. This is the error I get when trying to install the latest version of DKMS.

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-dkms_7.0.10-dfsg-2_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 202752 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-dkms_7.0.10-dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Deleting module virtualbox-7.0.6 completely from the DKMS tree.
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (7.0.10-dfsg-2) over (7.0.6-dfsg-1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (7.0.10-dfsg-2) ...
Loading new virtualbox-7.0.10 DKMS files...
Building for 6.4.10-060410-generic
Building initial module for 6.4.10-060410-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.4.10-060410-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.4.10-060410-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--install):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/make.log for more information." What does it say? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/21796 maybe helpfull.